# Expected Delivery Date on Transactional Email

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add "Expected delivery date" in the Transactional Email of Magento. Can anyone please tell me the predefined variable (or code) for expected delivery date in magento. If there are no predefined variable in magento for expected delivery date, is there another solution?

Comment: You may want to post more detail on your logic in estimating the delivery date.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, there is no logic for a "Estimated Ship Date" or "Estimated Delivery Date". Magento doesn't know when you ship or what days you work.

However a few companies have already developed modules for this. So your options are to develop your own module, or obtain the 3rd party modules that already do it.

Here are a few of the 3rd party modules:

- http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/delivery-date-and-notice.html
- https://www.wyomind.com/estimated-delivery-date-magento.html (not sure if this does emails though)